# Hidden text over iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, hover

I've just started delving into HTML/CSS and I've run into a problem. I'm trying to place hidden text over a Spotify iFrame so that when I hover over the iFrame, the text becomes visible and the iFrame becomes slightly transparent.

Here's the code I have:

HTML

```
<iframe source="..."></iframe>
<p class="hiddentext">Testing</p>
```

CSS

```
iframe{
  padding:20px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.hiddentext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

iframe:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

iframe:hover .hiddentext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When I try running it, the iFrame becomes transparent, but the text does not appear. If I set the visibility to visible and the opacity to 1 in .hiddentext{} the text is there so I would assume there is a problem with the iframe:hover .hiddentext{} part. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

add this way `:hover` css

```
iframe:hover + .hiddentext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8wr8fa2p/

Comment: there does seem to be another issue (sorry!). if you hover your mouse over the text, it shutters and phases in and out of the opacity.. any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change you code

```
<style>
iframe {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
}
.hiddentext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 103px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}    
iframe:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}    
#test:hover p {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>


<div id="test">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    <p class="hiddentext">Testing</p>
</div>
```